# AVPlayer stops loading tracks in lock screen

Tags: ios, avplayer, ios10

I was developing an app in which I'm receiving audio files from airdrop in inbox folder of the app and playing them with `AVPlayer`. I have turned on the background mode for audio playback. But when I lock the iPhone and current music file ends, next file doesn't load from inbox folder. But I also have audio in main Document folder, there everything is working fine.
Any help in this?

Comment: Can you show some code? Are you using an `AVQueuePlayer`?

Comment: No I'm using AVPlayer. Code for which part you want to see?

Comment: I even reported this bug on https://bugreport.apple.com. I don't know I will get any reply on that or not. Anyone know?